# NodeJs Spawn Docker commands

Tags: node.js, docker, spawn

I am trying to run a docker command to backup the database with Node spawn.

The problem is that the process exits with code 1.

If i try this command directly in the console it works.

How should i do?

```
     const backupProcess = spawn('docker', [
                'exec', container, 'pg_dumpall', `-U ${dbOptions.user}`, '>', `${path}`
            ]);
//container: container name
//dbOptions.user: database user
//path: backup file destination
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the '>' as argument to docker, but if you execute this in a shell the > is interpreted by the shell and not by docker.

You could try starting a shell wich starts docker and handels the redirect of the output.

```js
const backupProcess = spawn('bash',['-c', `docker exec ${container} pg_dumpall -U ${dbOptions.user} > ${path}`]);
```

Comment: This is not a best practice, particularly if you don't have perfect control over all of the variables.  If I set `container = '; cat /etc/passwd;'` then I can run any command I want using this line (a _shell injection attack_).

Comment: (And remember that, if you can run any `docker` command at all, you can `docker run -v /:/host -u root ...` to get unrestricted access to the host filesystem, editing any file as root – this is a very serious security vulnerability in this context.)